# GA runRealtimeReport API: Error customEvent is not a valid dimension

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am getting an error when calling `AnalyticsData.Properties.runRealtimeReport` using a "customEvent" dimension as follows:

Google script code (customEvent dimension):

```
function getRealTimeEvents(propertyId){
   var metric = AnalyticsData.newMetric();
   metric.name = 'eventCount';
   var dimension = AnalyticsData.newDimension();
   dimension.name = 'customEvent:ws_status';

   var request = AnalyticsData.newRunReportRequest();
   request.dimensions = [ dimension];
   request.metrics = [ metric ];
   var report = AnalyticsData.Properties.runRealtimeReport(request,'properties/' + propertyId);
   Logger.log(report)
}
```

This is error I get when executing the `AnalyticsData.Properties.runRealtimeReport`:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to analyticsdata.properties.runRealtimeReport failed with error: Field customEvent:ws_status is not a valid dimension. For a list of valid dimensions and metrics, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/realtime-api-schema

I already run the API to get the GA real-time metadata and checked that ws_status dimension is listed there:

```
{
  "apiName": "customEvent:ws_status",
  "uiName": "WS Status",
  "description": "An event scoped custom dimension for your Analytics property.",
  "customDefinition": true,
  "category": "Event-scoped Custom Dimension"
},
```

I was able to get data running the Explore report in GA so the ws_status dimension is listed there and the explore shows data against this dimension.

On the other hand, I do not have any issues using a **customUser** dimension, so in my case, the API is now working when I attempt to use a **customEvent** dimension.

I would appreciate any hint you can share

Answer (score 2):

The [Data API realtime reporting documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/realtime-api-schema)  mentions that "Event-scoped custom dimensions are not currently supported in the Realtime API".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hope event-scoped custom dimensions are available soon in the Realtime API.